# default variable values for logstash

Tags: logstash-grok

Is there a document on what are the default values for variables in logstash?
like:

```
break_on_match => true
named_captures_only => true
```

Similarly what is the default codec and other default values.

Received an event that has a different character encoding than you configured. `{:text=>"Sc=\x80\u0013 (from the logs it is Sc=€) expected_charset=>"UTF-8", :level=>:warn}`

How to overcome this error?

Comment: Add you log input which you give to logstash and the config that you use currently. Unless you give complete information on what is the problem what have you tried so far and what are other details it not possible to give a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Grok filter in logstash has a documentation which can be easily found if you search for 'grok logstash document'. The exact link to a summary of all the fields and their default value is as below:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#_synopsis_125

Basically Grok is a Filter plugin and Codec is altogether a set of plugins which can be used in Input and Output Configuration. I would suggest you to read basic information about Logstash Configuration Structure and plugins. You can find relevant information here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/configuration-file-structure.html

Codec includes a number of different plugins and all of them have a dedicated document page. Each Input and Output plugin will have a default codec value, however, this value depends on which Input/Output plugin it is. In your question you have not mentioned which Plugin's default codec value you need.

Comment: What is the default codec for input and output plugin?? The reason i am looking for this is because I get error with UTF-8 exception. I am not able to figure out why there is an error.

Comment: Update your question accordingly. Mention your error, the config you are using and logstash log.